# unable to boot simulator for ios8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ios8

updated xcode 6.0.1, can't boot simulator for ios8, it's working for ios7 no problem. tried to uninstall xcode, still no luck. tried to launch simulator, still for ios8 simulator can't boot, but ios7 works. anyone have ideas, Thanks so much.

my os is OS X 10.9.5

I tries just launch simulator, just not able to boot ios8 simulator, I also tries delete everything and added again.

I tried reinstall xcode, still doesn't work, this really drive me crazy, thanks so much

Comment: You should add some more details like logs and similar.

Comment: What is version of your OSx?

Comment: update your os and it will solve your problem.